# Silex - Best Practice for Client Choice Response Format (JSON / XML)

Tags: php, routes, request, response, silex

I would like to know the best coding practice that allows the client to define the response format for the request he made, which can also include filters, conditions, sorts, etc ...

I made a small template for an answer, I do not know if it is a best practice, but it works (advice is welcome). I coded no Middleware after();

PS: The choice of format will be dynamic after building the request code.

Now about a requisition. I figured I'd code any middleware before(). What is the best way to do it?

Follow the code:

**index.php**

```
<?php

define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
chdir(ROOT);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'src/Config/bootstrap.php';
require 'src/Config/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$app = new Application();

$app['serializer'] = function(){
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
    return new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
};

$app['debug'] = true;

/*$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app){
  $request->query->
});*/

$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
  //var_dump($response);
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  return $response;
});

return $app;
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

$app->mount('/classificados', require 'src/App/Controllers/ClassificadosController.php');
```

**ClassificadosController.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$classificados = $app['controllers_factory'];

$classificados->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $post = array(
        'title' => 'Titulo',
        'body'  => 'corpo',
    );

    $serializeContent = $app['serializer']->serialize($post, 'xml');
    return new Response($serializeContent, 200);
});

return $classificados;
```

What is the best way to build a logic to dynamize the response format (json or xml) for the client?